# Method to obtain real-time crowdsourced location information

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, geolocation

I'm relatively new to mobile development and have a question: Is it possible to use the Google Maps API (or other services) to determine user location for crowdsourcing location data?

For example: How Google implements its traffic density on Google Maps (busy areas and low-traffic areas)? Is it easy to imitate this idea using the Google Maps API and/or other API's?

If so, can anyone point me to possible resources where I can get started?